# Pax Exam / Karaf - Install Feature on test setup

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, pax-exam

I am attempting to integration test a Karaf feature with Pax Exam but I cant work out how to install a feature in my `config()` method.

Pax Exam is version 2.6.0 and Apache Karaf 2.3.2.

This is my config method:

```
@Configuration
public Option[] config() {
    return new Option[]{karafDistributionConfiguration().frameworkUrl(
            maven().groupId("org.apache.karaf").artifactId("apache-karaf").type("zip").versionAsInProject())
            .karafVersion("2.3.2").name("Apache Karaf").unpackDirectory(new File("target")),
            keepRuntimeFolder()};
}
```

Individual bundles can be installed with `mavenBundle("group", "artifact", "version")` but there seems to be no mechanism to install a Karaf feature with Pax Exam.

I am able to install features pragmatically in a setup method annotated with Junit `@Before` but it too late to get my services injected with @Inject.

Is it possible to install Apache Karaf Features in the `config()` method of a Pax Exam Test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all I strongly suggest to use the latest version of Pax-Exam (3.3.0), it does provide Karaf support out of the box. 
Second you're able to install features directly in the `config()` method. 
For example:

```
features(maven().groupId("org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features")
       .artifactId("standard").type("xml").classifier("features")
       .versionAsInProject(), "http-whiteboard")
```

You'll find a working sample at my [github](https://github.com/ANierbeck/Camel-Pax-Exam-Demo/blob/master/route-control/src/test/java/de/nierbeck/camel/exam/demo/control/route/KarafRoutingTest.java)